# Sending an SMS to a web page?

Tags: android, asp.net, windows-phone-7, sms

I want to send an SMS text message to my website so that the posts show up on a page. What services are available that can store the messages or send them to a website as CSV or something?

Comment: you "should" be able to ask for "advice" on SO. Asking how to do XYZ isnt great when you dont have clear requirements. With all due respect you guys wouldnt understand the mind of analysis and customer facing interaction as you are heavy coders.

Comment: I think you have misunderstand about SO. Please read **http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions**

Comment: That doesnt mean i have to agree with the status quo.

Comment: Agree or disagree that what its all about.  If you read that you know what kind of question you can ask here. I didn't made the rules here :)

Comment: @sp-1986: Actually, you have to follow the rules outlined in the [faq].  Failure to do so may result in your account being blocked from asking questions.  This can happen automatically when you have too many questions downvoted or closed.

Comment: @Will, actually my questions are fine. Some are nOObish but they are fine for the most part. The point i am making is SO should allow for analysis/advice and questions related to project management from the inception stage of the life cycle.

Comment: we can continue this debate on META if you like.

Comment: @sp-1986 "whiteboard" questions are totally fine on [programmers.se]; in fact we encourage them there.  Here we like to encourage practical, answerable questions that relate to your real-life programming issues.  Of course, a good question that is barely on topic works, but not so good questions that are barely on topic get downvoted by the community.  This question isn't that good primarily because it is answerable by a bunch of links.  We don't like link-only answers; they rot.  Hell, in a year I'll probably be back here deleting AurA's answer because the links rotted.

Comment: If you want further clarification, you can ask why  or debate for a broader scope for StackOverflow on (yes) [meta].  Just be aware that downvotes there mean disagreement.

Comment: I created a question on META once questioning the way things were run on SO and it got deleted. I wrote something about being able to ask project management questions as well as questions relating to customer interaction such as training and hand over process. Obvious to me that "they" dont like that because it doesnt adhere to the programmer mentality. Maybe its a pride/arrogance thing?

Comment: http://smallbutdisorganized.com/2010/09/19/why-are-so-many-programmers-arrogant/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the language you are asking for as you mentioned android, asp.net and windows phone in the tags.

The asp.net solution
http://www.c4sms.com/codeExamples.asp

For android
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

For windows-phone-7
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_send_an_SMS_in_Windows_Phone_7

Comment: Thank you, shame about the down-voters